# Can someone explain to me the "for loop"?

Tags: python-3.x

for z in ("Ronaldo", "Julio"):

inv = "Hi " + (z) + " Please"

I want to print "Hi Ronaldo Please" and "Hi Julio Please" but when i type "print(inv) it only prints the last one, why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: Indentation is significant in Python and you haven't included any in your question's code, which makes it hard for anyone else to know what you're doing. Indent by an extra four spaces and Stack Overflow will format the code nicely, too!

Comment: It's very hard to tell exactly what your code is.  Paste it into your question exactly how it is, highlight it, and hit Ctrl-k to make it a code block.  My guess is that you didn't indent your `print` call far enough.

Comment: Books and tutorials are *designed* to explain such things. Stack Overflow isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `for x in y:` loop, the program executes the indented block for every value in `y`. On each iteration, you can access the value by the name `x`. With your program

```
for z in ("Ronaldo", "Julio"):
    inv = "Hi " + (z) + " Please"
print(inv)
```

the flow goes like this:

1. `z = "Ronaldo"`
2. Evaluate `"Hi " + (z) + " Please"` -> evaluates to `"Hi Ronaldo Please"`
3. `inv = "Hi Ronaldo Please"`. From now on, inv has the value `"Hi Ronaldo Please"`
4. Next round of the `for` loop, `z = "Julio"`
5. Evaluate `"Hi " + (z) + " Please"` -> evaluates to `"Hi Julio Please"`
6. `inv = "Hi Julio Please"`. From now on, inv has the value `"Hi Julio Please"`
7. End of for loop - we covered all values.
8. Run `print(inv)` - this prints the current value of inv, `"Hi Julio Please"`.

As you can see, we ran print just once, and it printed the latest value of `inv`. Instead, you want to run print in the for loop, like this:

```
for z in ("Ronaldo", "Julio"):
    inv = "Hi " + (z) + " Please"
    print(inv)
```

With this construction, during each run of the for loop, something is printed.

Comment: If this (or any other) answer has solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141962). Thanks!